# TextToSpeech.OnInitListener.onInit(int) being called continuously

Tags: android, text-to-speech

I'm getting reports that, on some (not all) HTC Desire HD (FRF91, 2.2) and HTC EVO 4G ( PC36100|3.29.651.5, 2.2), the `TextToSpeech.OnInitListener.onInit(int)` is being called repeatedly (over 1500 times in the space of a few seconds) on the same object. This behaviour does not occur for any of my other users (or with other Desire HD users) AFAICT.

The code is:

```
TextToSpeech tts = new TextToSpeech(context, new TextToSpeech.OnInitListener() {
    private int mCallCount = 0; // trying to investigate potential infinite loops

    @Override
    public void onInit(int status) {
        if ((mCallCount % 100) == 1) {
            // report this
        }
        mCallCount++;
    }
});
```

Anyone any ideas?

EDIT: I have also tried calling the `shutdown()` method (the first time multiple listener calls are detected) but this doesn't seem to help.

Comment: elaborate please!! what is status?? when is it getting updated?

Comment: The status is SUCCESS (AFAICT). That's about as much as I can decipher from the Flurry reports. It only happens to about 1 in 1000 users, but for those users it does happen to, it consistently happens.

Comment: Where is the code that enables the TTS service?
What else are you doing inside of `onInit()` that you are leaving out?
It is possible that something is re-triggering.
Also, did you test everything if there is no TTS resources installed?  Your 1-in-1000 users may be the ones with it not loaded.  The TTS service will still initialize (you can still play earcons but not speech).

Comment: Reproduces on emulator for me. Android 2.2, with SVOX Classic TTS engine installed, working via the TTS Extended service. I do NOTHING in onInit.

Comment: What part of activity lifecycle are you initiating TTS?  Please check whether activity lifecycle events are being generated, that causes you to re-initialize TTS.  We use TTS extensively in one of our apps, and have never seen this behavior.  Make sure you try it with NO TTS resources installed; in that situation it can trigger an activity asking the user whether to install TTS.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have any of the offending devices available to test on. I could push one of these answers to my production code and use analytics to see if they work, but this is clearly something I would rather not do (for fear of breaking something). If anyone can confirm one of these answers solves this problem then I will be happy to give it a try in my production code.

Comment: I am running code on Jellybeans emulator onInit being called twice() and that's why I came here to find an answer, what's going on ? I am instatiating TTS in a service

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you should get around it with your own intermediary method, for example:

```
private long lastCall = 0;
private long deepBreath = 5*1000; //5 seconds
private boolean hasRested;

TextToSpeech tts = new TextToSpeech(context, new TextToSpeech.OnInitListener() { 
    @Override 
    public void onInit(int status) { 
        long thisCall = Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis();
        intermediaryMethod(status, thisCall);
    } 
}); 

//new method
public void intermediaryMethod(int status, long thisCall) {
    hasRested = (thisCall-lastCall)>=deepBreath;
    if (hasRested) {
        lastCall = thisCall;
        //do something about 'status'
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This may or may not help, but I had a similar problem when call tts from a service, luckily for me I was better off doing my tts from an activity which solved the problem.

If you do this, and it is appropriate, make sure your manifest for the activity has:

```
android:finishOnTaskLaunch="true"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to create object of the Textospeech before on create ie. globally .try this code and check is it still calling many times????

```
public class TtsActivity extends Activity implements OnInitListener {

private int MY_DATA_CHECK_CODE = 0;

private TextToSpeech tts;

private EditText inputText;
private Button speakButton;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    inputText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.input_text);
    speakButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.speak_button);

    speakButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {          
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String text = inputText.getText().toString();
            if (text!=null && text.length()>0) {
                Toast.makeText(TtsActivity.this, "Saying: " + text, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                tts.speak(text, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_ADD, null);
            }
        }
    });

    Intent checkIntent = new Intent();
    checkIntent.setAction(TextToSpeech.Engine.ACTION_CHECK_TTS_DATA);
    startActivityForResult(checkIntent, MY_DATA_CHECK_CODE);

}

protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == MY_DATA_CHECK_CODE) {
        if (resultCode == TextToSpeech.Engine.CHECK_VOICE_DATA_PASS) {
            // success, create the TTS instance
            tts = new TextToSpeech(this, this);
        } 
        else {
            // missing data, install it
            Intent installIntent = new Intent();
            installIntent.setAction(TextToSpeech.Engine.ACTION_INSTALL_TTS_DATA);
            startActivity(installIntent);
        }
    }

}

@Override
public void onInit(int status) {        
    if (status == TextToSpeech.SUCCESS) {
        Toast.makeText(TtsActivity.this, 
                "Text-To-Speech engine is initialized", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    else if (status == TextToSpeech.ERROR) {
        Toast.makeText(TtsActivity.this, 
                "Error occurred while initializing Text-To-Speech engine", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}

}
```